# Can i Mix Recommended Transmission fluid?

Tags: automatic-transmission, suzuki, transmission-fluid, grand-vitara

I have a Suzuki Grand Vitara 2008 Model with a 2.4L Engine (Automatic Transmission) which has a recommended transmission fluid of Suzuki ATF 3317 or Mobil ATF 3309. I bought this car 2nd hand so I don't know which one the previous owner used.

So I'm planning to buy the Mobil ATF 3309 and I'm assuming that the previous owner used Suzuki ATF 3317.

Are they safe to mix?

More Info: I got the radiator changed due to a coolan leak so the transmission fluid got abit low

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make darn sure there is **no** coolant in the transmission.  I would suggest a complete drain including the torque converter, and then using the fluid (OEM compatible) of your choice.

However, to answer your question, if the fluid is compatible, it's compatible.  Only a complete teardown of the transmission would remove every last little bit (there's a lot of pockets in servos and the valve body that never completely drain).  So by definition, different compatible fluids must be allowed to mix.

Okay to mix compatible fluids.